# Extending u-boot functionality

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, boot, gpio, u-boot

I need to add some new features to u-boot like pressing specified button to setup my device using blinking LED as a device response. The problem is that I don't where u-boot starts to execute C code. What file should I modify?

I use STM32F429I-Discovery for testing and have already installed everything I need to run kernel using buildroot. One of the LEDs (GPIO_13) is constantly blinking, so, I tried searching for the code that provides such functionality. It looks like led.c and gpio_led.c must do the thing but changing them gives nothing.

**Update.**

Well, I was trying to dig into triggers but it looks like modifying .dts file doesn't have impact on LED blinking. Commenting code in the corresponding heartbeat-trigger turns off the LED, however, there is no GPIO choice, so, I cannot change the green LED to the red one. After moving "linux,default-trigger" to GPIO14 in the .dts file I recompile u-boot and linux with buildroot but nothing changes. Here are my changes (I took some code from stm32f746-disco.c):

**stm32f429-disco.dts**

```
/dts-v1/;
#include "stm32f429.dtsi"
#include "stm32f429-pinctrl.dtsi"
#include <dt-bindings/input/input.h>

/ {
    model = "STMicroelectronics STM32F429i-DISCO board";
    compatible = "st,stm32f429i-disco", "st,stm32f429";

    chosen {
        bootargs = "root=/dev/ram";
        stdout-path = "serial0:115200n8";
    };

    memory {
    reg = <0x90000000 0x800000>;
    };

    aliases {
        serial0 = &usart1;
    };

    leds {
        compatible = "st,leds";
        red {
            gpios = <&gpiog 14 0>;
            linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
        };
        green {
            gpios = <&gpiog 13 0>;
        };
    };

    gpio_keys {
        compatible = "gpio-keys";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        autorepeat;
        button@0 {
            label = "User";
            linux,code = <KEY_HOME>;
            gpios = <&gpioa 0 0>;
        };
    };

    /* This turns on vbus for otg for host mode (dwc2) */
    vcc5v_otg: vcc5v-otg-regulator {
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        gpio = <&gpioc 4 0>;
        regulator-name = "vcc5_host1";
        regulator-always-on;
    };
};

&clk_hse {
    clock-frequency = <8000000>;
};
```

**stm32f429-discovery.c**

```
#include <common.h>
#include <dm.h>
#include <ram.h>
#include <spl.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <asm/armv7m.h>
#include <asm/arch/stm32.h>
#include <asm/arch/gpio.h>
#include <asm/arch/stm32_periph.h>
#include <asm/arch/stm32_defs.h>
#include <asm/gpio.h>

DECLARE_GLOBAL_DATA_PTR;

int dram_init(void)
{
    int rv;
    struct udevice *dev;

    rv = uclass_get_device(UCLASS_RAM, 0, &dev);
    if (rv) {
        debug("DRAM init failed: %d\n", rv);
        return rv;
    }

    if (fdtdec_setup_memory_size() != 0)
        rv = -EINVAL;

    return rv;
}

int dram_init_banksize(void)
{
    fdtdec_setup_memory_banksize();

    return 0;
}

u32 get_board_rev(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int board_early_init_f(void)
{
    return 0;
}

int board_init(void)
{
    gd->bd->bi_boot_params = CONFIG_SYS_SDRAM_BASE + 0x100;

    struct gpio_desc gpio = {};
    int node, offset_node;

    node = fdt_node_offset_by_compatible(gd->fdt_blob, 0, "st,leds");
    offset_node = fdt_subnode_offset(gd->fdt_blob, node, "green");
    if (node < 0)
        return -1;

    gpio_request_by_name_nodev(offset_to_ofnode(offset_node), "gpios", 0, &gpio, GPIOD_IS_OUT);

    if (dm_gpio_is_valid(&gpio)) {
        dm_gpio_set_value(&gpio, 1);
    }

    return 0;
}

#ifdef CONFIG_MISC_INIT_R
int misc_init_r(void)
{
    char serialno[25];
    uint32_t u_id_low, u_id_mid, u_id_high;

    if (!env_get("serial#")) {
        u_id_low  = readl(&STM32_U_ID->u_id_low);
        u_id_mid  = readl(&STM32_U_ID->u_id_mid);
        u_id_high = readl(&STM32_U_ID->u_id_high);
        sprintf(serialno, "%08x%08x%08x",
        u_id_high, u_id_mid, u_id_low);
        env_set("serial#", serialno);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LEDs are defined in the device tree (U-Boot file arch/arm/dts/stm32f429-disco.dts, Linux kernel file arch/arm/boot/dts/stm32f429-disco.dts)

```
        leds {
                compatible = "gpio-leds";
                red {
                        gpios = <&gpiog 14 0>;
                };
                green {
                        gpios = <&gpiog 13 0>;
                        linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
                };
        };
```

In Linux you can change the trigger by writing to the appropriate trigger file. This should be

/sys/class/leds/green/trigger

The U-Boot driver for GPIO is drivers/gpio/stm32_gpio.c

You can use function dm_gpio_set_value() to set a GPIO as input and dm_gpio_get_value() to read the value.

You may want to use the FASTBOOT part of board/st/stm32mp1/stm32mp1.c as a template.

Comment: It definitely did something. However I broke my buildroot but it was the first time I managed to change something on the board successfully. I just need to study how to rebuild everything properly. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I updated the question. Looks like changes in the .dts file are not applied. Even deleting "linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";" doesn't prevent the green LED from blinking. After rebuilding u-boot .dts is renewed. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: U-Boot incorporates a device tree for the initialization of drivers using the 'driver model'. Typically you would not use this device tree to boot Linux but load the device tree coming with Linux from a file and pass its address to the U-Boot boot command. - So you, please, check which of the two device trees you have manipulated.

Comment: You are right, I used wrong .dts file, now I'm able to change blinking LED color. But I still cannot turn on any LED during boot time using uboot. I was searching for methods that could allow me to parse GPIOs from the device tree (updated the code) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the u-boot functionallity in the board.c file. Which can be found at:  u-boot/board/stm/stm32f429-discovery/board.c

You might need to change other settings, which can be done in the header file. This file can be found: u-boot/include/configs/stm32f429-discovery.h

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only thing that is left is to reach the pin somehow to toggle it but it's a problem for another topic. :)